# Is it possible with the MRTK to make a slate rotate to the users hololens position using components?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

Design Breakdown: I am designing a showcase design of a building environment which has a floorplan and videos / tooltips to present key info.

Issue: I am able to play videos through slates which is effective but i want to improve it but making the main video demonstator to be anchored but rotate around depending on where the user is.

Query: Is there a plausible way to design it with components within the slate itself or will it need development of a new script to make it work?  I'd like to try to do it without new scripting if possible but if unable, I will work on scripting.

Attempts: Using Facing user and facing camera alternative. Attaching a pointer on the camera for the object to look at to aid rotation.  Muddling with the default settings of a slate player.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Billboard component](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/mrtk_development/Assets/MixedRealityToolkit.SDK/Features/UX/Scripts/Utilities/Billboard.cs) to have an object stay in place but face the user.

Here is an example configuration of a quad (plan) that will stay in place but pivot along y axis to face the user:

[image]